# Cannot start Hive Web UI

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am facing a problem to start the Hive web UI. Although the hive-hwi-0.11.0.war file did exist under /usr/local/hive-0.11.0/lib/, the same error message always appeared when I tried to start HWI:

> ...FATAL hwi.HWIServer: HWI WAR file not found at /usr/local/hive-0.11.0/usr/local/hive-0.11.0/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war

It seemed that the $HIVE_HOME path was repeated twice when the .war file was being searched regardless how I set the value for hive.hwi.war.file.

Values that I have tried:

> setup 1: ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war
>
> setup 2: /usr/local/hive-0.11.0/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war
>
> setup 3: lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war

BTW, I set up all the hive configurations in $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml. Anyone has a solution for this issue? Thanks!

Below is my hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hive.cli.print.current.db</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.cli.print.header</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://client2/metastore</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
        <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hive</value>
        <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>hadoop</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.servermode</name>
        <value>thrift</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>master1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://client2:9083</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.hwi.listen.host</name>
        <value>10.19.209.100</value>
        <description>This is the host address the Hive Web Interface will listen on</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.hwi.listen.port</name>
        <value>9999</value>
        <description>This is the port the Hive Web Interface will listen on</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hive-0.11.0/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war</value>
        <description>This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post your hive-site.xml configuration

Comment: I have updated my original post to include hive-site.xml. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you echo $HIVE_HOME? You don't mention OS, but I am assuming Linux.. Did you edit your .bashrc file and add that path variable? It is not finding the WAR because of the incorrect Path. You must be setting it elsewhere. Check your .baschrc file or any additional startup scripts that could be setting that $HIVE_HOME var.

Comment: I created a hadoop.sh file under /etc/profile.d/, in which I set up all the path variables related to hadoop, and echoing $HIVE_HOME shows the correct hive path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're setting $HIVE_HOME and then passing the full path in the hive-site.xml resulting in the incorrect path that you see in your error output.

Try changing the hive-site.xml file by just passing the lib location to append to the already set $HIVE_HOME path variable as follows:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
    <value>/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war</value>
    <description>This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
</property>
```

Then restart Hive and try the WebUI again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @apesa's answer, you **might** need to add two more properties along with what @apesa mentioned.

```
<property>
      <name>hive.hwi.listen.host</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0</value>
      <description>This is the host address the Hive Web Interface will listen on</description>
</property>

<property>
      <name>hive.hwi.listen.port</name>
      <value>9999</value>
      <description>This is the port the Hive Web Interface will listen on</description>
 </property>
```

**hive.hwi.listen.host** and **hive.hwi.listen.port**  are optional only if the things are working with the default values.

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: He already has those entries in his hive-site.xml posted above, but you definitely need them.